# Interfaces and child classes

Tags: c++, interface, derived

In C++, I have a class **FooA** and a class **FooB** that both are child classes of a base class **Foo**. FooB has to implement `interface` **Bar**. If I only have a Foo pointer to a FooB and wish to use FooB's Bar methods, I would have to do a cast. However, that seems to violate `polymorphism`.

I'm wondering if there's a better approach to allow FooB to implement the Bar interface without forcing all Foo derived classes to also implement Bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redesign your classes. Chances are inheritance isn't what you need here.

Rationale: If you have a `Foo` pointer somewhere, then its owner shouldn't need to know whether it points to `Foo` object or `FooB` or any other derived object - it only uses `Foo` functionality, ignorant of the implementation. (That's how polymorphism works in general.)

In other words: If you have a `Foo` pointer and its user depends on functionality only in `FooB`, then that pointer should be of type `FooB` in the first place.

Comment: That makes sense although I'm not sure how I would redesign the class to handle this. Right now, I have another set of classes BazA and BazB that take either a FooA or a FooB pointer. They are created by a factory that takes a Foo pointer and casts it appropriately. If I were to not use inheritance, I wouldn't be able to pass a pointer into the factory.

Comment: In that case it may make sense for the factory to have two methods, `BazA createA(FooA* a)` and `BazB createB(FooB* b)`. No need to cast in this situation.

Comment: I might help you with the design but I don't know the problem you're modelling. If you want to refactor your code to leverage polymorphism, then you need to a) specify clearly the abstraction represented by `Foo` and its interface, and b) consider which modules can refer to this abstraction (`Foo`) and which depend on concrete implementations (`FooA` or `FooB`) - the less of these, the more benefit from polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, I did some more thinking (and searching) about solidifying the interface and coincidentally I ran across the [interface segregation principle](http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/isp.pdf). It seems what I want to do is have the base class implement all the interfaces required by its derived classes. Then limit the access of a client that depends on a specific concrete derived implementation to only the methods specified through the specific interface.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to only use Foo pointer, and call Bar methods, Foo must implement the Bar interface. It's the only way to let your compiler know that the Foo object can used this method, without the cast of course.